# Turning plain text into NSString

Tags: objective-c

I have a list of words like: hello hi bonjour etc.
I'm literally adding `@""` around every word manually. It's not bad, but when you have thousands of words it can get really tedious. Is there a method, where you input a bunch plain text like hello hi and it turns it into: `@"hello"` `@"hi"`, which I can then copy into code, or do I have to do this manually?

```
the
be
and
of
a
```

Comment: It's unclear.  Do you want a programmatic way to do this, perhaps starting with a properties string, or a way to edit your source, with, perhaps, "keyboard macros"?

Comment: In what format is your list? It would be best to include the list in your bundle and extract the strings you need from there. It's 100% certain you don't need to add @"" a thousand times. But without more detail it is impossible to give a concrete answer

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to read words in from a file? Hard code a list or words into the code? Do you simply not care to have @"" around strings across your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done in similar cases is use an editor's text replacement feature to replace all blanks with (in your case) `" @"`.  You may have to get a bit fancier if you don't have blanks at the start and end of each line, or you have multiple adjacent blanks, etc, but the general technique works.

Comment: I thought my answer was right but the more I think about it, the more correct (in terms of the OP's question) your answer seems to be. So +1 to you.

Comment: Do you know which editor to use? I've googled xcode's  substitution option, but it doesn't seem to do what I want it to?

Comment: @user2608474 - For the simplest case just do "Find" in the editor, select "Replace" with the widget at the top left of the editor window, put a blank in the search text line and `" @"` in the replacement text line.  Then do "replace and find" a few times to check the result, then "replace all".  There are numerous tricks of the trade beyond that.  (I have never found a list of the Xcode editor's find tokens for newline, et al.  Maybe someone else will know those.)

Comment: @user2608474 - Of course, always experiment on a copy of the file, not the original.

Comment: If these are newline separated, then if you hit ctrl-q, the next character typed will be entered and not interpreted.   I.e. if you type `ctrl-q` followed by `<return>`, it enters the `<return>` character into find field.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is NSString's [`componentsSeparatedByString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a) method.  You can enter in a bunch of plain text into some text field or text view, get the raw string, and then push that through "`componentsSeparatedByString:@" "`" (make sure there's one space in there) and out comes an array of words.

Answer (score 0):

You could try loading the strings from a Plist -- inserting them into code is kind of ugly. Something like `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:urlToMyPlist]` or `[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:urlToMyPlist]`

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the docs for NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithCharacters%3alength%3a) and you'll find the `-initWithCharacters:length:` method, which you can use to create strings. If you have a string that you want to break up into smaller strings, use `-componentsSeparatedByString:`.